# Finding the integral points of the hyperbola $x^2 -y^2 - Ax - By = 0$, for certain positive $A$ and $B$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

sorry if this matter was already discussed but I would like to try to see from another point of view...

Consider the hyperbola $x^2 -y^2 - Ax - By = 0$ where $A,B>0$.

For a certain choice of $A$ and $B$ I know that this hyperbola has 12 integral points.

But I can know (with some geometrical tricks) only 8 of them and I need to find only the last 4 ones.

I have heard about Vieta Jumping or Pell equations but I really don't know where I have to start...
My "concept" is to start from one (or more) known points and deduce the other ones by finding any property or law or something else that link them together...

Can someone help me ? 
Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: Please show the eight points you can find, so that it's clear what the "last 4 ones" are supposed to be. (Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3550347/edit) to include further details.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Vieta jumping or much of anything else. The restriction to few points means that there are just a few ways to factor as $MN = A^2 - B^2$ with the restriction that 
$$ M \equiv N \pmod 2 $$
but allowing for positive or negative $M,N$ and change of order. Then it may be possible to solve
$$  (2x+2y-A+B) = M,  $$
$$ (2x -2y-A-B) = N   $$
using integers $x,y.$ Indeed, adding gives
$$ 4x = M+N +2A $$ while subtracting gives
$$ 4y = M-N +2B, $$ or
$$ x = \frac{M+N+2A}{4} \; \; , \; \; y = \frac{M-N+2B}{4}  $$

==============================================

ORIGINAL:

$$ x^2 - Ax - y^2 - B y = 0  $$
$$ 4x^2 - 4Ax - 4y^2 - 4B y = 0  $$
$$ 4x^2 - 4Ax + A^2 - 4y^2 - 4B y - B^2 = A^2 - B^2  $$
$$  (2x- A)^2 -(2y+B)^2 = A^2 - B^2    $$
$$  (2x- A+2y+B)(2x-A -(2y+B)) = A^2 - B^2    $$
$$  (2x- A+2y+B)(2x-A -2y-B) = A^2 - B^2    $$
$$  (2x+2y-A+B)(2x -2y-A-B) = A^2 - B^2    $$